# Adding email addresses to MailItem.To using semicolon in Outlook 2007 addin

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am trying to add email addresses to MailItem.To using semicolons. It is currently not appending:

```
myMailItem.To = myMailItem.To + ";"
```

If I am able to append, I will be able to add other email addresses.

Please help me in this.

Comment: What _is_ happening? Errors? Warnings? Exceptions? Nothing?

Comment: Did not get any error or warning. Simply I am getting same Value as before concatenation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `To` is just a representation of something that is internally (probably) stored as a list, I guess the To setter removes any trailing semicolons. Thus, add the semicolon together with the mail address you want to add:

```
myMailItem.To = myMailItem.To + ";" + newAddress;
```

Or, even, better, do [as recommended in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220513%28v=office.11%29.aspx)...

> **To Property**
>
> [...] The Recipients collection should be used to modify this property.

...and use the `Recipients` property:

```
myMailItem.Recipients.Add(recipient1);
myMailItem.Recipients.Add(recipient2);
...
```

Comment: Sorry This is typo, I changed as myMailItem.To = myMailItem.To + ";";

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of the [`To`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.to.aspx) property:

> This property contains the display names only. The To property corresponds to the MAPI property PidTagDisplayTo. The Recipients collection should be used to modify this property.

You should be adding to the [`Recipients`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipients.aspx) property.

```
myMailItem.Recipients.Add(rec1);
```